# IIS 5.1 ASP.NET not working

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I have IIS 5.1 on Windows XP Pro Sp3 x86. I ran aspnet_regiis -i and -c but when I got to run a simple ASP.NET file, everything else shows but the asp.net command shows and doesn't show the result

```
<html>
<body>
 <p>The time is now @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is off of w3schools website tutorial for ASP.NET

Here is the result when being displayed on the browser

> The time is now @DateTime.Now

If someone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *sidenote:* You trust w3schools? oops. Read http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: How is this both asp.net and asp-classic?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>The time is now <%=DateTime.Now().ToString()%></p>
```